Askers blocked from editing details due to "spam"
There were a few occasions where askers weren't able to include details in their questions because the system blocked their post due to "spam".
Examples:

Here, the system seems to prevent codeblocks without links or images
In this example, the author was blocked from adding some things but they posted a link in the comments which leads to what they actually wanted to post.
Here, the author fixed the issue by replacing http(s):// with ... and @ with 'at'
The author wasn't able to add their outputs here and they provided a link to another site where they posted the outputs.
The author of this question said they couldn't post all of the output and it contained many links

Is this specific to the Staging Ground or is this a general thing? If it only happens in the Staging Ground, why/can this be removed?
Are there limitations on codeblocks or the amount of links in a question? If there is a limit of the amount of links, should this be disabled on codeblocks?

Maybe related on MSE: Does restricting the number of links for new users do any good?
